# Making API calls while app is killed/not actively running

Tags: java, android, api, firebase-cloud-messaging

So I am making an app that has to check for some information, but I need to be able to do that while the app is killed/not actively running. So basically like Youtube's notifications or something. I am a beginner and watched some tutorials on FCM, which can send a notification while the app is killed, which is fine. However, I need to be able to periodically make API calls, check if a certain condition is true and send the notification if so (all of that while app is not running). I tried googling that and found nothing that can help me. So... any ideas? (No code included since I don't think it's relevant.)

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. Although a good question, it is always a good idea to add some code, to show the community your efforts.

Comment: @rainer Yeah, but my code is just an API call and some `textView.setText();` so I don't think it'll help, really :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) to request periodic runs of your code. It may be set up to broadcast a message time to time to your receiver (declared in AndroidManifest.xml or in your code).

It will work while device is on. To continue after reboot, you have to set up a receiver for [Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) and register it in your code (not in AndroidManifest.xml, as it no longer works in latest versions of Android).

Answer (score 0):

If this condition only affects the display of notifications, you can simply check the condition when you receive a notification through FCM. Here's an example :

```
class FCMService : FirebaseMessagingService()
{
    override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage)
    {
        val myCondition = getConditionFromAPI()

        if (myCondition) {
            showNotification(message)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Right. But how do I make it so that I don't have to send a notification through the console but receive one when the condition is true and the app is not running?